# Make a transition to a route + ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I define my routes like:

```
MainApp.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("memes", {
        path: "/memes"
    });
    this.route("map", {
        path: "/map"
    });
});
```

I know that I can transit to another route in side of a controller like:

```
this.transitionTo("memes");
```

My question is: How to transit to another route outside of ember? Imagine that I've a JavaScript method like this:

```
function makeOutsideTransition(route){
     //make ember transition
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
function makeOutsideTransition(route){
    window.location.assign('#/' + route);
}
```

Or something like this. If it's outside your ember app, you can simply use the js functions.